# How to write a huge table (>10GB) column by column (column-wise) in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, io

Basically what I'm doing is calculating a vector and then writing the results.  Right now I'm writing it row by row then I have to transpose is after with `datamash transpose` which is kind of annoying.  It would be way more efficient **if I could write a tab-delimited table column-by-column.**

**How can I do this in Python (can it be down w/ np.savetxt)?**

Here's one of my attempts below:

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: data = np.random.normal(size=(10,3))

In [14]: data
Out[14]:
array([[-0.50469426, -0.9710173 ,  0.43285955],
       [ 0.71702597, -0.99998294, -1.00353228],
       [ 0.77699465, -0.66542361, -0.04594868],
       [-0.71012566, -1.46451086, -0.95308903],
       [ 0.47470605, -0.56792278,  0.95818696],
       [ 1.20729071, -0.04735589, -0.11576503],
       [ 1.03686861,  0.72149358,  0.35908901],
       [ 0.09520535,  0.24437775, -0.59554944],
       [-0.13346795,  0.29530724,  0.17524018],
       [-0.16433609,  0.05261348, -0.57545287]])

In [15]: with open("example.tsv", "w") as f:
    ...:     for row in data:
    ...:         print(*row, sep="\t\n", file=f, end="")
    ...:

In [16]: %%bash
    ...: cat example.tsv
    ...:
    ...:
-0.5046942610111921
-0.9710173002083825
0.43285954686999120.7170259682395401
-0.9999829435149956
-1.003532284093560.7769946455220355
-0.6654236121150638
-0.04594868270526936-0.7101256559235657
-1.4645108615674511
-0.95308903163753660.4747060486691834
-0.5679227787239494
0.9581869616594761.207290709055818
-0.047355888296561795
-0.115765032633420781.036868614074581
0.7214935810053711
0.35908901158512140.09520535113648704
0.2443777544867152
-0.5955494427027563-0.1334679518044996
0.29530724431573385
0.1752401825058493-0.1643360874489238
0.052613481327433834
-0.5754528683216069
```

Comment: You can (1) Use two files: Fro each row read already written columns from one file, add new column and write it to the other file. Then delete first file and repeat. (2) Write rows with enough free space to be overwritten later with additional columns.

Comment: How about transposing the numpy row & column first, then saving to .csv file?  The general writeline object in Python reads one line at a time, so there is no clean way around it. Or, use a different library for large datasets such as tensorflow that will handle this for you?  Tensorflow is the way to go if you handle 10gb+ data sets frequently.

Comment: My main concern was not having to load everything into memory at once.  I wanted to transpose it because then I can iterate line by line with 2 files in parallel (they have the same structure) to do a particular analysis.  I can only do this if they are transposed :/

Comment: @O.rka **Aha, you first mentioned using two files**. The more care here - as explained below, an idea of coding a **for**-iterator in standard python is ***devastating** the process performance*. Best results will be with python letting do both the { heavy | light }-computations and iterations ( best smart-aligned into numpy-broadcasts and vectorised-code expressions ) inside **numpy**-tools. That way one receives best performance possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Having 10 GB of data: it's worth start with a few remarks first :

Unless you data processing pipelines are outside of your control and you have to use anyway the plain-text, GNU datamash text-file transformations, the `numpy`-side is an absolute master in smart vector/array processing, if one decides to harness all its powers:

**Key factors are:**

- in-RAM-layout: **`numpy`** can change this in a snap, as it tricks you by handling axes abstract
- on-disk-layout: **`numpy`** can read both **`F`**-like (FORTRAN, column ) **`C`**-like (row-wise) data-files

This said, your python side is thanks to `numpy` as flexible as the crowd of scientific computing developers was already used to design, develop and performance tune. Fortran has used the column-first ordering since ever due to performance advantages, so it has been put into `numpy`-tools right for performance reasons since ever either.

---

### The `numpy` smart in-RAM-layout tricks:

```
|>>> from zmq import Stopwatch
|>>> aClk = Stopwatch()
|>>> aClk.start(); a = np.arange( 1E3 );aClk.stop() #_____ tiny arrays are cheapest
46                                                  #_____ ~ 46 [us]+may live in-cache
|>>> aClk.start(); _ = np.arange( 1E6 );aClk.stop() #_____ small arrays are "fast"
10131                                               #_____ ~ 10 [ms] to alloc. RAM
|
|
|>>> aClk.start(); _ = np.arange( 1E8 );aClk.stop() #_____ going 1E8+ SWAPs a lot
23970419                                            #_____ ~ 24 [s] + O/S SWAPs RAM
+0:00:34.974360
|
|>>> _.shape                      (100000000,)
|>>> _.size * _.itemsize           800000000
|>>> _.dtype                       dtype('float64')
|>>> _.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : True  <--------+--- vectors are {C|F}-contiguous blocks
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : True  <--------+
  OWNDATA         : True  <------------ indeed owns own data + may have cheap "np.view"-s
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
```

in-RAM-layout is a bit hidden issue and if you have never been into `numpy`-tricks and performance tweaking details, might be, this is the first place you hear about this.

```
|>>> aClk.start();_ = _.reshape( _.shape[0]/10, 10 );aClk.stop() # ___ make 1E8 array into [1E7,1E1] shape
24                                                               # ___ ~ 24 [us]
# i.e. NOTHING HAS MOVED in memory, just the hidden indexing tricks were adapted
#      not a single byte from all of the 0.8 GB, now array, has been moved
#      the same will happen with numpy.ndarray.T smart-tricked operations
|>>> _.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : True  <--------- vector ceased be vector, matrix is C-row-wise
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : False            as not a single byte was moved in in-RAM-layout
  OWNDATA         : False <--------- now, view-alike manipulations on "foreign"-owned data
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
```

The smart tools can "transpose" ( actually doing nothing but indexing tricks ) in almost zero-time:

```
|>>> aClk.start();_.shape;aClk.stop()
(10000000, 10)                              #             BLOB is [1E7,1E1] ~0.8 GB
25                                          # ... 23 [us] to tell us the .shape
|>>> aClk.start();_.T.shape;aClk.stop()     #             go TRANSPOSE !
(10, 10000000)                              #             ok BLOB is [1E1,1E7]
43                                          # ...~43 [us]
                                            #    -23 [us] to tell us the .shape
                                            # ==  20 [us] to TRANSPOSE BLOB ??????
                                            #             NO transpose is tricked by adapted indexing only
```

The transpose operation just changes the way, how indices get mapped-onto an already RAM-allocated memory-area, all without moving a single byte of the 0.8 GB sized BLOB-data in the RAM, just smart-indexing tricks - so the **column-wise arrangement** could be used as it **comes at zero add-on costs** ( not counting those `~ 20` microseconds ... )

```
|>>> _.T.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : True <------------- now, F-column-wise arrangement gets set
  OWNDATA         : False <------------ and, again, on "foreign"-owned data
  WRITEABLE       : True                                               already
  ALIGNED         : True                                               put in-RAM
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
```

Anyway, doing any high-performance, smart and vectorised code for a bit larger datasets, one will always benefit from taking due care about in-RAM-layout and tuning the vectorised-code to "follow" ( not fight against ) the actual layout used. Best read about cache-memory hierarchies for your processor/computing-platform and for ultimate performance always test each ordering scenario for the target scales of vectors/n-dim-arrays, before making the vectorised-code into HPC-production (cache-lines, associativity of caches are very different and HPC-impacts are indeed immense if your code "violates" the best alignment possible and such code wastes a lot of time right due to such inefficiencies ).

---

### One may spend a lot or smart-save in using on-disk-layout tricks :

as noted above, unless forbidden to do so, one may increase the performance of on-storage ops, by smart-compression first all the output the `numpy` is to store on-disk. Be it a `numpy` way or `dill.dump()` or similarly developed compression-library.

Starting from the exemplified code above:

```
In [15]: with open("example.tsv", "w") as f:
    ...:     for row in data:
    ...:         print(*row, sep="\t\n", file=f, end="")
```

is very expensive, as the **`for`**-loops are particularly slow ( expensive ) in python and the whole job could be done smarter using the "HPC"-grade `numpy`-tools.

Additionally added data-compression is both fast per-se and way cheaper than moving data onto storage and back. SSD-media are faster than conventional media, yet ( in 2019 ) the benefits from compression remains smaller data-footprint and faster I/O-data-flows, which in most if not all cases justifies the time spent in using **`numpy.savez_compressed()`** to move just the compressed ( `.ZIP_DEFLATED` ) blob, instead of always spending 8-bits-per-each-digit in ASCII-file plain number representations.

`numpy.load()` is an input-direction call for the `numpy`-case, `dill` can even save/restore the whole python-interpreter session, which may have a wider use in scientific workflow automation ( plus saving restore-able-snapshots )

python also provides **`zipfile`** tools for direct work with compressed-files, so a need to resort to GNU command-line tools may be limited to some indeed corner-cases.

Comment: Thanks for you very detailed answer.  So it looks like np can read column wise but we’re you suggesting to write the file, load it in, and then reshape it?

Comment: No, I did not suggest adding any artificial step. I did suggest to best "align" the numpy vectorised processing ( where one can cheaply transpose, if ever needed any matrix ) with tools for both input / output of columnar data-files and to review the current file-representation, if it ever needs to get GNU datamash-transposed, as you have posted in the O/P ( when it was demonstrated that the **numpy**-tools can do this in a very smart way, tricking the indexing, as if all has taken "in-place" ). I also did suggest **never use** a python **for**-iterator in cases a numpy-vectorised code fits.